# Flatten JSON with jq retaining key names

Tags: json, key, jq, flatten

I'm trying to flatten a JSON consisting of nested objects. The top layer contains several key/value pairs, where each value is itself an array of a number of objects (the bottom layer).

What I would like to get, using jq, is simply an array of objects containing all the objects of the bottom layer, each of which with an additional key/value pair identifying the top-layer key it originally belonged to.

In other words, I would like to turn a JSON

```
{
 "key1": [obj1, obj2],
 "key2": [obj3]
}
```

into a plain array

```
[OBJ1, OBJ2, OBJ3]
```

where each `OBJi` is simply the original object with an extra key/value pair

```
"parent-key-name": keyx
```

where `keyx` would be the top-layer key `obji` belonged to, i.e. `"key1"` for `obj1` and `obj2`, and `"key2"` for `obj3`.

I'm struggling with the fact that when referencing the objects in the bottom layer, e.g. via .[], jq does not seem to have inbuilt functionality to access associated top-layer information. However, I'm new to jq, and hope there is an easy solution after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following input :

```
{
 "key1": [{"name":"Emma"},{"name":"Bob"}],
 "key2": [{"name":"Jean"}]
}
```

You can divide your items to entries, store the key in a variable and add the value for each item in `value` object:

```
jq  '[ to_entries[] | .key as $parent | .value[] |
   .["parent-key-name"] |= (.+ $parent) ] ' test.json
```

which gives the following output :

```
[
  {
    "name": "Emma",
    "parent-key-name": "key1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "parent-key-name": "key1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jean",
    "parent-key-name": "key2"
  }
]
```

Comment: It would be simpler and better to write:  [ to_entries[] | .key as $parent | .value[] | .["parent-key-name"] = $parent]   OR  [ to_entries[] | .key as $parent | .value[] + { "parent-key-name": $parent} ]

Answer (score 1):

The solution presented below consists of two steps, each of which might be helpful separately, e.g. if someone wants to "flatten" the JSON in a slightly different way.

1. First, let's make the changes to obj[i] "in-place":

   with_entries( .key as $k | .value[] |= ( . + {"parent-key-name": $k} ) )

Example:

```
$ jq -n -c -f program.jq
```

Input:
    {
     "key1": [{a:1}, {a:2}],
     "key2": [{b:3}] 
    }

Output:

```
{
  "key1": [
    {
      "a": 1,
      "parent-key-name": "key1"
    },
    {
      "a": 2,
      "parent-key-name": "key1"
    }
  ],
  "key2": [
    {
      "b": 3,
      "parent-key-name": "key2"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. To flatten, simply append `| [.[]]` to the above filter. This produces:

   [[{"a":1,"parent-key-name":"key1"},{"a":2,"parent-key-name":"key1"}],[{"b":3,"parent-key-name":"key2"}]]